# What is the module responsible for the signup form?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, customer-account

In magento 1.9, I want to extend the signup form but couldn't find the module responsible for it.

Comment: Customer module is responsiblefor signup form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In magento 1, `app/code/core/Mage/Cusotmer` module is responsible for Sign up and login action.

Customer module is used ful for customer related action.

Answer (score 0):

Include @Rakesh's Answer : In Below Path you can extend `sign-up` form

`frontend\yourtheme\default\template\persistent/customer/form/register.phtml`

**or**
you can override `this` file by creating custom module